# Incorrect result while using SemanticImport for CSV file import

Tags: bugs, import, dataset, csv-format

I might use this incorrectly. I want to use a `.csv` file that (as list) looks like:

```
{{"Group", "data 1", "data 2"}, {"a", 1, 5}, {"a", 2, 3}, {"a", 4, 5}, {"b", 8, 9}}
```

Now I want this as a `Dataset`, i.e. I try and import it with `SemanticImport` and would want to have as result

[image]

However, I can't get it to work with `SemanticImport`.

I can use the following code, but hoped `SemanticImport` would basically replace this:

```
Import["testdata.csv"];
dataDim = Dimensions@data;
a1 = Transpose@
   Table[data[[1, i]] -> data[[1 + j, i]], {i, dataDim[[2]]}, {j, 
     dataDim[[1]] - 1}];
testFullAss = Association[a1[[#]]] & /@ Range[dataDim[[1]] - 1];

Dataset[testFullAss]
```

Comment: If you can tell me how I can add a file to my question I will do. But basically, if you Export the list at the beginning at my question as a .csv file, you'll have the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using

```
SemanticImport["testdata.csv"]
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

on the exported data you provided which is the dataset you seek. But
`SemanticImport` has been reported to have a few bugs, maybe that's why you can't get it to work. In the meantime, and in between time, you can use the much cleaner approach to obtain your dataset after using `Import` on your file:

```
data = {{"Group", "data 1", "data 2"}, {"a", 1, 5}, {"a", 2, 3}, {"a", 4,  5}, {"b", 8, 9}};
```

Then:

```
Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ data, #] & /@ Rest @ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, that's weird you get the correct result. But at least it in principle appears to work. Thanks for the much shorter code you provided, which I will use in the meantime.

Comment: @MockupDungeon. You're welcome :)

Comment: Setting `dset = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ data, #] & /@ Rest @ data]` and `din = SemanticImport["data.csv"]`, note that `dset === din` gives `False`, because as the `FullForm`s reveal, they have different values for `Association[Rule["ID"...`. What's the best way to extract just the datasets, without their IDs, so as to be able to compare?

Comment: @murray, that's a good observation. I hadn't noticed that. I'll look into it.

Comment: @murray, One way will be to do `Normal[dset] == Normal[din]` which yields `True` as expected.

Comment: @RunnyKine: Ouch, I should have thought of `Normal` since it works in so many other similar situations where one has extra stuff in an object. (`Series`, `SparseArray`, `GraphicsComplex`, ...)

Comment: @murray, have you tried `TimeObject[] // Normal`?  has no effect in 10.0.1, unlike `DateObject[] // Normal`.