# How to get data from DB into dataset with keys

Tags: histograms, dataset, databaselink

I'm a *Mathematica* newbie and I have the following problem: I connect to a *Oracle DB* and read out a set of variables, further on I want to histogram some of the variables. A Dataset seems to be the right tool, but I produce only datasets without a key via:

```
DBtest = SQLSelect[db, "TABLE1", {"ID", "VAR_1"}]

Dataset[DBtest]
```

Result is a `Dataset` with one column containing `ID` and the other containing `VAR_1` (sorry for the generic names - I can't copy my real work, since it contains sensitive data).

Then I can't use the `DBtest[Histogram, "key"]` functionality, since there is no `"key"` available.

Is there anyway to add keys after filling the dataset from the `DB`? Or shouldn't I use the `Dataset` class?

Comment: You have to thread the keys "ID" and "VAR_1", like RunnyKine's answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59684/incorrect-result-with-semanticimport/59687#59687   ... `Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ data, #] & /@ Rest @ data]`

Comment: Perfect! Now it works, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discussion purposes, let's use some data from *Mathematica's* [example databases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/UsingTheExampleDatabases.html):

```
$connection = OpenSQLConnection["publisher"];

$dbTest = SQLSelect[$connection, "SALESDETAILS", {"TITLE_ID", "QTY_ORDERED"}]

(* {{"PY2002", 75}, {"PY2002", 10}, <<17>> , {"CK4017", 20}, {"CK4016", 20}} *)
```

We can create a histogram directly from this data without wrapping it in a `Dataset`:

```
Histogram[$dbTest[[All, 2]]]
```

[image: histogram screenshot]

As observed in the question, a `Dataset` with this data carries no column names since the original result set is comprised of lists instead of associations:

```
$dataset = Dataset[$dbTest]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

However, the columns are still accessible by their indices:

```
$dataset[Histogram, 2]
```

[image: histogram screenshot]

When we retrieve the original SQL data, we have the option of including a header row by means of the `"ShowColumnHeadings"` option.  We can use the headers from this row to create associations that provide names for our columns:

```
$dataset2 =
  SQLSelect[$connection, "SALESDETAILS", "ShowColumnHeadings" -> True] //
    Inner[#2->#1&, Rest@#, First@#, Association]& // Dataset
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Now we can produce histograms using the column names:

```
$dataset2[Histogram, "QTY_ORDERED"]
```

[image: histogram screenshot]

Comment: This solution works as well. And the definition of `$dataset2`, including the SQL connection, is quite elegant. The way to produce histograms without using `Dataset` at all, was new for me. Thanks!